# Setting "Chrome Type" to "None" for a web part using power shell

Tags: 2013, web-part, powershell

I have added a custom web part on page.

Some how I am not been able to change its Chrome Type to None because when I mouse over the corner of web part where the arrow is supposed to show under which you see "Edit Web Part" option, the arrow is not displaying.

I don't know what the problem is, may be due to some javascript conflict the corner arrow for this web part is not being shown.

How do I set its chrome type through power shell or other means?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following powershell code,

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://Server:1111/")
$web = $site.OpenWeb("/")
$resultsPath = "Pages/default.aspx"
$page = $web.GetFile($resultsPath)
$page.CheckOut()
$wpm = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($resultsPath, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
$wpm.WebParts | ft Title, StorageKey 
$refinerManager = $wpm.WebParts | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "Webpart Title Name"}
Write-Host $refinerManager
$refinerManager.ChromeType = "None"
$wpm.SaveChanges($refinerManager)  #ERROR
Write-Host "Done"
$page.CheckIn("Test")
$page.Publish("Test")
$web.Close()
$site.Close()
```

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32330f27-b866-4895-baa5-e03a3a4db0ad/cant-save-a-webpart-from-powershell?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Have a look at the below links to change the Chrome Type programmatically using c#,

1. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1289b677-ae77-45f5-8a21-176e42737ca9/how-do-you-programmatically-set-chrometype-of-web-parts-on-web-part-page?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy
2. http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/10/17/programmatically-changing-the-properties-of-webparts-and-views-in-sharepoint-2010/