# How do you set the default chrome type for an app part?

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-addin

I am displaying an app part in a page and by default the Chrome Type of the app part is set to "Default". I would like this set to None so that there is no title displayed on the page. How can I do this as neatly as possible?

I currently have an `Elements.xml` file with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ClientWebPart Name="ChromelessWebPart" Title="Make me chrome less" Description="Example of a chromeless app part" DefaultWidth="300" DefaultHeight="200">
    <Content Type="html" Src="~remoteAppUrl?{StandardTokens}" />
  </ClientWebPart>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to wss.xsd (%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML), the parameters for ClientWebPart are Name, Description, Title, DefaultWidth and DefaultHeight. There might not be a solution to do this from elements.xml

You can set the chrome type manually or using code, but I believe you already know that. For code to set the chrome type check out the answer for [Setting "Chrome Type" to "None" for a web part using power shell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83115/setting-chrome-type-to-none-for-a-web-part-using-power-shell)