# Setting Default Option for Chrome in a Web Part

Tags: 2013, web-part

Currently I've got a ticket to set the Chrome to "None" on web parts in our site where it should have been set to "None" but it was overlooked.  I went ahead and did that manually but was wondering if there was a way to set the default option in the drop down globally to "None" for Chrome in a web part (unless the web part tried to override the Chrome setting itself).  Any ideas on if/how to accomplish this?

Comment: If you want to do it with powershell, there is a similar question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83115/setting-chrome-type-to-none-for-a-web-part-using-power-shell

Comment: Interesting link though it needs apply more going forward than anything else, thanks though!